# '<sc:Text' is not showing any text when I put the 'OutputCache' directive, why?

Tags: sitecore, outputcache

It works fine without it, but I need the 'OutputCache' enabled for this usercontrol/syblayout. how can I enable it?

`Page_Load`, `Page_PreRender` is not fired when OutputCache is present.
How can I cache my datasource then?

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="120" VaryByParam="none" VaryByCustom="RAWURL"  %>

    <%-- Tabs --%>
        <div class="product-tabs">         
            <nav>
                <ul class="  aa">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tab1">
                        <li class="item selected">
                            <a data-content="content-tab-1" href="#0" runat="server" id="lblTab1">
                                <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Tab 1 Text" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tab2">
                        <li class="item">
                            <a data-content="content-tab-2" href="#0" runat="server" id="lblTab2">
                                <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Tab 2 Text" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tab3">
                        <li class="item">
                            <a data-content="content-tab-3" href="#0" runat="server" id="lblTab3">
                                <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Tab 3 Text" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="tab4">
                        <li class="item">
                            <a data-content="content-tab-4" href="#0" runat="server" id="lblTab4">
                                <sc:Text runat="server" Field="Tab 4 Text" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                  </ul>
              </nav>           
          </div>
```

Comment: Are you configuring the sublayout on presentation details?

Comment: And try to use varyByData attribute to see if it works

Comment: What does your VaryByCustomString code do?

Comment: `GetVaryByCustomString` is fine, it's been called in Global.asax, returns `context.Request.RawUrl`

Comment: it's got personalization rules, will `varyByData ` work?

Comment: @AngJobs, it may works. You may test for it by adding the attribute on it. But if you are configuring the sublayout on the Presentation Details, it is preferable that you cache it from the Rendering Parameters. Moreover, you may also add the OutputCache on the Layout itself